# Excel Summing specific cells

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I want a single cell to contain the sum of the cells adjacent to cells with a `#DIV/0!` [image]

So see how I can get the total % I have accumulated, but I also want to add the % that I have not yet had a grade for (which are the cells with `#DIV/0!` and account it in under the "missing (%)" column. Basically the sum of every cell left of a cell in column E that contains `#DIV/0!`. Any suggestions or ideas? I am very inexperienced with excel and only know basic formulas.

I have tried something like `=SUMIF(D3:D16,ISERROR(E3:E16))` to no avail. (The values start in row 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree that avoiding the `#DIV/0!`'s is best, the sum can be done as is.

Try this formula, entered as an Array Formula (complete with Ctrl-Alt-Enter)

```
=SUM(D3:D16*ISERROR(E3:E16))
```

BTW, if using Excel 2007 or later, to avoid errors you should use

```
=IFERROR(A1/B1,"Value you want instead of error")
```

Comment: If I change it so that I avoid `#DIV/0!` then I cannot use this method, but thanks for the workaround, it technically answers the question so I'll accept it.

Comment: If I did avoid the `#DIV/0!`, and had 0's instead, how would I go about getting the total % i could have obtained out of the ones I have not taken (ones with 0)?

Comment: like this `=SUMIF(E:E,"<>0",D:D)`

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to avoid generating the #DIV/0 errors by using a formula like:
`=IF(ISERROR(A1/B1),0,A1/B1)` in column E.
This will return A1/B1 if there is no error, otherwise it will return 0. (You could also print -1 to identify the errors)
Once you have no errors in the column, you should be able to use SUMIF.

Comment: Good idea actually, why didn't I think of that

Comment: Still I would like to find a way to sum conditionally and independently, say I wanted to find the maximum % I could have achieved?